# Ivy repository structure for module with multiple builds (profiles)?

Tags: ant, ivy

I'm using Ant and Ivy for dependency management in a .NET shop and have been having a lot of success, but I can't figure out a solution for this issue.  My question pertains to the repository structure for modules that have several different profiles (for lack of
a better term).  For example, the module (it's a 3rd party library - Castle) I'm trying to setup in the repository has been compiled against different versions of the .NET platform.  This distribution has the following directory structure:

- net35/Castle.Core.dll
- net40clientprofile/Castle.Core.dll
- sl3/Castle.Core.dll
- sl4/Castle.Core.dll

My ivysettings.xml file has the File Resolver setup as this:

```
<filesystem name="fs.resolver" cache="nn.repo.cache">
    <ivy pattern="${repository.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[shortRevision]/[revision]/ivy.xml" />
    <artifact pattern="${repository.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[shortRevision]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" />
</filesystem>
```

At first, I thought configurations could be used for this, but didn't
make much progress.  How can I specify an artifact in the Ivy.xml file with the same name more than once?  I don't think you can.  Also, if I add subdirectories in the repository will I
have to modify my artifact pattern in ivysettings.xml?

What is the recommended approach with Ivy to setting this module up?
What would the Ivy.xml file for this module look like?  How would the
ivysettings.xml file need to be modified for this?

Hopefully I don't have to create separate modules for each different compilation of the same version of the library.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ivy you can add [extra attributes](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/concept.html#extra) to module artifacts.

Project setup:

```
|-- build.xml
|-- ivysettings.xml
|-- ivy.xml
`-- repository
    `-- myorg
        `-- Castle
            `-- 1.0
                |-- ivy.xml
                |-- net35
                |   `-- Castle.Core.dll
                |-- net40clientprofile
                |   `-- Castle.Core.dll
                |-- sl3
                |   `-- Castle.Core.dll
                `-- sl4
                    `-- Castle.Core.dll
```

**ivy.xml**

Use a configuration mapping to choose which artifact to download:

```
 <ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.demo" module="demo"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="myorg" name="Castle" rev="1.0" conf="default->net35"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**ivysettings.xml**

The artifact pattern includes an [extra attribute](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/concept.html#extra) called "profile"

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="local"/>
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml" />
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[profile]/[artifact].[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

**repository/myorg/Castle/1.0/ivy.xml**

The [extra attribute](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/concept.html#extra) "profile" is used to differentiate between the artifacts within the module. The configurations are used to enable configuration mapping by client modules.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="Castle" revision="1.0" status="release"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="net35"/>
        <conf name="net40clientprofile"/>
        <conf name="sl3"/>
        <conf name="sl4"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="Castle.Core" type="dll" e:profile="net35" conf="net35"/>
        <artifact name="Castle.Core" type="dll" e:profile="net40clientprofile" conf="net40clientprofile"/>
        <artifact name="Castle.Core" type="dll" e:profile="sl3" conf="sl3"/>
        <artifact name="Castle.Core" type="dll" e:profile="sl4" conf="sl4"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for that. In regards to your answer, since the extra attribute and the configuration have the same values, couldn't I just use [conf] for the artifact pattern instead of adding an extra attribute?  Can you use [conf] in ivysettings for the file resolver?

Comment: The same thought occurred to me. However, it doesn't work that way. Try it, you'll discover it attempts to use the value "default" for the [conf] part of the artifact pattern.... That is because "default" is the configuration being mapped in the dependency declaration. It's difficult to describe, but extra attributes is the mechanism to add additional metadata to the artifacts within a module. Configurations on the other hand is a mechanism to decide which artifacts are retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, this will help a lot.